# I need to use `OR` in SQL but in other way because i can't use `OR`

Tags: sql, logical-operators

I write a lot of information which might be not useful for you so if you want a simple question this is my question : (i want to know is there anyway to use `OR` on SQL in other ways like this : `WHERE age=18,19 AND gender='male','female'` OR something like this :  `WHERE age=[18,19] AND gender=['male','female']`) but if you didn't understand what i want you can read more information in below.

Hi i have many `foreach` function to make custom filter and i can't finish it, in my sql code i have a search value at first which will search in all of columns and its work well.

I have 4 Select input which will help me to filter it i mean select boxes like age or gender or other things.

But the problem is , the select boxes are able to select multiple options as array and creating this kind of SQL is very hard.

I made 4 `foreach` for my sql and its works until i just use one of my select boxes which means its not gonna work if i choose age and gender or something else because the sql will be something like that :

`WHERE age=18 OR age=19 OR gender='male' OR gender='female'`

AND the sql which im looking for is :

`WHERE age=18 AND gender='male' OR age=18 AND gender='female' OR age=19 AND gender='male' OR age=19 AND gender='female'`

But this is just an example and the code which i write will need very heavy SQL and its will be slow at first and i will die to fix it on `foreach` functions so i want to know is there anyway to use `OR` on SQL in other ways like this : `WHERE age=18,19 AND gender='male','female'` OR something like this :  `WHERE age=[18,19] AND gender=['male','female']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like `IN`... For example:

```
WHERE age IN (18,19) AND gender IN ('male','female')
```

Comment: This is the exactly thing which i want thanks a lot

Comment: @GoldenGuard I am glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

This could be an option

```
WHERE (age, gender) in ((18,'male'),(18,'female'),(19,'male'),(19,'female'))
```